# Entity Framework Code First Multiple Object setup

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

I have question on properly setting up entity framework between a few objects.
The three objects/tables are:
Company, Orders, Channels
Company is one to many to Orders
Company is one to many to Channels
Channels is one to many to Orders

When I set them up as follows I get the "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths" error.

```
public class Order
{
    /// <summary>
    /// System Generator OrderNumber
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Company associated to this order
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("MerchantId")]
    public virtual Company { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ID of the channel that provided this information
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("SourceChannelId")]
    public virtual Channel { get; set; }
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }
 }
 public class Company
 {
     public List<Order> Orders{get;set;}
     public List<Channel> Channels{get;set;}
 }
 public class Channel
 {
     public List<Order> Orders{get;set;}
 }
```

I know that I could eliminate the link to company from order by going to channel and then to company but there is a case where an order may not have a channel.  But there is never a case where an order would not have a company. There is also a third object with a one to many relationship to order but I can figure that out if I get the first two working correctly :)

I would prefer to use dataannotations method but fluent is fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not just an issue with Entity Framework but rather with SQL. You couldn't do the same thing even there either.

By the default, Entity Framework is set to create Cascade Delete when removing a parent.

Imagine now this scenario:

- You have entity A
- You have entity B which has FK to entity A
- You have entity C which has FK to entity A and FK to entity B

You trigger delete for entity A which now has two delete paths for entity C:

- C deleted via FK to A
- C deleted via FK to B which is deleted via FK to A

And this is something that SQL can not handle as it does not know which path has priority and this is called multiple cascade delete paths.

There is only one way to solve this AFAIK and it requires fluent API. You need to set one of your FK's of entity C to be Cascade Delete = false.

Cascade delete can be turned off globally in Entity Framework like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

**EDIT:**

This will remove deletion path from A to C, but will keep A-B-C path.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Orders)
                .WithRequired(x => x.Company)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

}
```

Comment: Can I remove the foreign key from order to channel but still do a query similar to where order.channel.id = 5

Comment: What if I wanted to remove the cascading delete from just the channel. How do I do that in fleunt

Comment: Added an example on how to do it. This will remove one path, but keep another.